# Simple on 1st click trigger first function - on 2nd click trigger another function not working?

Tags: javascript, animation, menu, game-development

Morning all, got stuck on this one yesterday - couldn't figure out why it was not firing.

Trying to make it so that values will be pulled out of an array in another JS file when a menu is activated but then be deleted when the menu is closed. I had the values being pulled bit working but just cant seem to implement the values being deleted on the 2nd click.

I've checked the delete value function and it works when it is tied to another button.

```
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
        
burger.onClick(function() {
 
    toggleFlag ? first() : second();
    toggleFlag = !toggleFlag;
});

var toggleFlag = true;

function first(){
        burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
        if('nav-active')pullValue();
       });
         //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
};

function second() { deleteValue() };
```

Comment: Your code is setting `burger.onClick` which does nothing. It's `.onclick`. Also, the better way is to use `.addEventListener('click', fn);` which you're also doing, but inside the first click handler? This doesn't make any sense. And why would you delete some array if the burger menu is closed?

Comment: remove burger.onClick and use only burger.addEventListener('click'...), redundant code

Comment: Add you html code too

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys, i went with this in the end:

```
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
        
    function call(){
        if(callOne) one();
       else two();
       callOne = !callOne;
    }
    
    var callOne  = true;

    burger.addEventListener('click', 
    function one(){
        
            
            nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
          
            if('nav-active')pullValue();
            

            //Animate Links
            navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
                if (link.style.animation) {
                    link.style.animation = '';
                } else {
                    link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`;
                }
             });
         //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

    });



function two() { deleteValue() };
```